# Font size not working at all in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-size

Changing the font size with CSS is just not working in IE9. The font will change but the font size will not.
It works perfectly in chrome and firefox.
I tried to use em,pt instead of px. i tried font-size:40px. i tried everything.

The font size will just not change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font: 40px Arial;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    font size test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me. Have you tried `font-size:40px` (notice the `px`)

Comment: yes i have, just forgot to add that in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your CSS is overridden with you browser settings. Check the accessibility settings of the browser.

Comment: Thank you got it to work, for some strange reason "ignore font sizes" was checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: @Kyle Derpina what about encoding? Are you sure you are saving it as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tested this with the exact document you posted, then apparently your IE 9 is broken. Re-install it. Otherwise, please post a complete example code or a URL that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your zoom in IE9 is set to 100%.  To do this, Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> while in the browser.
2. Make another CSS definition is not overriding your font-size statement.  You can even force the font size by using the !important attribute like this:

   ```
   body {
     font-size: 40px !important;
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you are clearing your cache when you refresh the page.  To do a cache-free reload of a page, Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser.  This will flush the cache and reload the page completely.

As far as the code you posted, I copy/pasted it as is and it works as intended in IE9.  You may want to reinstall IE on your computer if you still can't get it working.